# ERROR running force:source:pull: Entity of type 'CustomApplication' named 'Contact' cannot be found

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm remove opportunity, case related list from contact layout. After remove I try to pull using sfdx:force:source:pull -u . But, unfortunately I got an error .
ERROR running force:source:pull:  Entity of type 'CustomApplication' named 'Contact' cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SjPnQAK).

Comment: Is there any workaround you can think of?
Should we pull in the metadata and then convert it to sfdx format?

Comment: It shows that issue as fixed, however I just ran into it today. 

Adding the artifacts sfdx force:source:pull couldn't identify to my .forceignore at least let me get the changes I needed into my scratch org.

Comment: On which object ?

Comment: I resolved my issue by adding the following things that were problems to my .forceignore:
ShiftTemplate.All_ShiftTemplates
ShiftTemplate.My_ShiftTemplates
ShiftTemplate.My_RecentShiftTemplates
ProductServiceCampaignItem.All_ProductServiceCampaignItems
ProductServiceCampaignItem.My_ProductServiceCampaignItems
ProductServiceCampaignItem.My_RecentProductServiceCampaignItems

Comment: Oddly enough I just spun up a new project and had the same problem with something named "AppBrand" of type "CustomApplication". 
Added it to the .forceignore to no effect, changed it to "AppBrand.app" did work however.